# Python boolean behavior at arrays

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, boolean

I have a question about an arrays and loops.
I'd like to get the information, if a specific element in the array has a certain value and then print weather it is true or false.

```
data = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
data = np.array(data)
[row,col] = data[:,:].shape

for i in range(row-1):
    for j in range(col-1):
        print(data[i][j] == 3)
```

But the output is

```
False
False
```

But this seems not right, because the matrix has 6 values and I only got 2 returned

Using

```
print(data == 3)
```

generates

```
[[False False  True]
 [False False False]]
```

How can I fix the for-loops?

Comment: You are using `numpy`, you shouldn't use loops to begin with

Comment: With `range(row-1)` and `range(col-1)` you're losing the right-most column and bottom row, leaving just `[[1, 2]]`. Drop the `-1`

Answer (score 0):

You should be using range(row) instead of range(row-1) and likewise for col.

Range is exclusive of the value you pass as the argument. In your example row = 2, therefore using range(row-1) is actually range(1), which will return the iterable [0]. col = 3, so for range(col-1) your doing range(2) which returns [0, 1]. Your current loop is only looking at the first row and first two columns, hence only 2 values returned instead of six.

Comment: Ah thank you. Yeah I need to get used to this range() function, because in other languages it was easier for me to handle the limits like i <= row or something like that